# Position de l'adverbe de temps avec le passé composé

Tags: indications-de-temps, ordre-des-mots, adverbes, passé-composé

Quelle est la variante correcte? Je pense que seul le premier exemple est correct, mais je ne suis pas certain.

> Je suis demain allé en Italie.
>   Demain je suis allé en Italie.
>   Je suis allé demain en Italie.

Answer (score 1):

Il n'est pas possible d'associer l'adverbe *demain* avec une forme verbale au passé, *demain* requiert obligatoirement un temps au futur.

On peut dire ces deux phrases :

> Demain, j'irai en Italie.
>   J'irai demain en Italie.

Avec une forme au passé, on dirait :

> Hier, je suis allé en Italie. (passé composé)
>   Je suis allé hier en Italie. (passé composé)
>   Hier, j'étais en Italie. (imparfait)

Answer (score 0):

demain means "tomorrow", so it can't be associated with a past tense (except maybe in "back to the future"). In any case it is usually placed after the verb :

> J'irai en Italie demain.
>
> Je suis allé en Italie hier.

But you can put "demain" in front if you want to stress it, but then you need a coma

> Demain **,** j'irai en Italie
>
> Hier **,** je suis allé en Italie

Answer (score 0):

La passé composé étant incompatible avec *demain*, on peut remplacer cet adverbe par *hier* afin de pouvoir analyser les phrases soumises.

> *Je suis hier allé en Italie.

Il est possible de placer certains adverbes de temps entre l’auxiliaire et le verbe (ex: *Je suis aussitôt/désormais/enfin/souvent/etc. allé en Italie*), mais *hier* (ou encore moins *demain*) ne peuvent pas s'employer pas ici dans la langue courante. Cette tournure serait possible en poésie.

> Hier, je suis allé en Italie.

C'est la forme la plus courante. Attention, il séparer l'adverbe faut une virgule.

> Je suis allé hier en Italie.

C'est aussi une forme possible mais ici, on insiste sur le fait que c'était hier et pas une autre date alors que dans la phrase « Hier, je suis allé...», on indique juste que l'on est allé en Italie, et accessoirement que c'était hier.

S'il fallait garder *demain*, le temps le plus probablement employé à l'oral serait le présent :

> Demain, je vais en Italie.

Mais à l'écrit ou dans un langage soutenu :

> Demain, j'irais en Italie.

Comment: J'ajouterais la forme "Je suis allé en Italie hier", forme assez courante également reléguant le complément de temps à la toute fin de la phrase lui donnant ainsi moins d'importance.